# how to get query string of kendo datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, query-string, kendo-datasource

I am using kendo grid to which data is provided by kendo data source. I am using quite a complicated filter and thats why I have to use parameterMap function to do some sorting and filtering. When the query is sent, the query string is automatically prepared by the data source and everything works fine. I need a way to store this url (at least the query string) for every read request. Is there a way to access it?

Answer (score 1):

After some research... that was pretty easy. It is enough to use decodeURIComponent before returning data in the parameterMap function:

```
 parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
     ...
     storeSomewhereTheValueOf(decodeURIComponent($.param(data)));
     return data;
}
```